# Polymer 2 IE11 syntax error when loading webcomponentsjs

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

I'm getting the following error when I view my component in IE11 after loading webcomponents-loader.js. I tried upgrading to use the latest psk, as suggested elsewhere but that didn't seem to resolve the issue. Any ideas??

[image: ie11 syntax error]

Comment: If you can post the code as well, please do it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell which code has the comment, but I know that it's generated by including webcomponentsjs on the page. Just to clarify, the comment is not being generated by my code.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of webcomponentsjs are u using?

there have been some "unstable" releases... I also similar errors on 1.0.5 and 1.0.6 if I remember correctly.

You could try 1.0.7 it was just release 3 days ago or go back to an earlier release.

Comment: Looks like I was using 1.0.0-rc.5. I just tried 1.0.7 and noticing the same error. What version worked well for you? I'll try 1.0.4 next.

Comment: Looks to be the same issue with 1.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing native-shim.js?  If I remember correctly I had to import that to get IE to work correctly.  (Well, mostly correctly, still fighting other issues.)

Comment: Strange, I'm seeing the same error when using native-shim.js